# How to centralize logging configuration, and use just log4j.properties?

Tags: java, log4j

I would like to configure logging in my application with `log4j.properties` and instruct (somehow) all third-party packages/modules to log through this configuration. Now they log differently and it's a mess: OpenEJB, Hibernate, Apache HttpClient, Jersey, etc. How can I do this? I want to work with `log4j` only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a framework which can redirect all kinds of logging frameworks to `log4j`: [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).

See "[Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)" for an overview.

**[Edit]** Maven `pom.xml` for slf4j:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.16</version>
  <!-- The usual exclusions here: javax.mail:mail, oro:oro -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had in mind, but their documentation is very unclear. Do you have any link that explains how my Maven `pom.xml` file should look like? What dependencies will it have (and what `<exclusions>`)?

Comment: Still the same situation, console is full of messages formatted in different style. OpenEJB uses one format, Hibernate another, and my own log messages are formatted as specified in `log4j.properties`

Comment: That is because jul adds a console logger during the startup of the VM. In your setup, enumerate all handlers for the root logger of jul and remove them. Also don't forget to install the jul bridge. See http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html